# How to add or subtract number to html element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to add/subtract from a number inside a span tag. This is depenent on a checkbox. Here is the jquery I'm trying:

```
//If checked
var $newprice = $("#totalprice").val() + 299;               
$("#totalprice").text($newprice);

//If NOT checked
var $newprice = $("#totalprice").val() - 299;               
$("#totalprice").text($newprice);
```

If I check the box, it adds 299, but unchecked changes the number to -299.

Comment: share your html code...

Comment: you need `parseInt()`

Comment: Can you show us some working code? @Garrettj944

Comment: Put your code in the change event of your checkbox that would work.

Comment: Sorry for not posting HTML, @PranavCBalan is the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For span you need to use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method to get content not **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**. In both case **[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** returns an empty string. In first case just string concatenation will be happen. In second case it will be `"" - 231` which results `-231`, where the empty string act as 0.

So you can use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)** with callback which hold index and old value, parse the old value and add or subtract value and return it for update.

```
//If checked
var $newprice = $("#totalprice").text(function(i,v){
    return parseInt(v,10) + 299;               
});
//If NOT checked
var $newprice = $("#totalprice").text(function(i,v){
    return parseInt(v,10) - 299;               
});
```

Comment: then that would be `299` if checked.

Comment: Thank you. So val() is more for checking input values I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in change event of your checkbox:

```js
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    //If checked
    var $newprice = +$("#totalprice").text() + 299;
    $("#totalprice").text($newprice);
  } else {
    //If NOT checked
    var $newprice = +$("#totalprice").text() - 299;
    $("#totalprice").text($newprice);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type='checkbox'>
  <span id='totalprice'>0</span>
</p>
```

`+$("#totalprice").text()` leading `+` would turn the text to number.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting method as well :)